# Почему не употребляется словосочетание "двое дочерей"?

Tags: количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

Мы знаем, что собирательные числительные двое, трое, четверо, семеро... с существительными женского рода не сочетаются, а с существительными мужского рода легко сочетаются,например: двое сыновей. Но подобное сочетание в форме "двое дочерей" не употребляется.   В чём причина?

Answer (score 1):

ОТВЕТ КАК ВЕРСИЯ, ТРЕБУЕТСЯ ОБСУЖДЕНИЕ

1. Сущ. женского рода  и небольшое количество  одуш. сущ. мужского (и общего) рода на А/Я относятся  к 1-ому склонению, например: мужчина и женщина. В Р.п. ед.числа они имеют одинаковое окончание Ы (нет мужчины, женщины).
2. Попробуем теперь образовать СЧЕТНЫЙ ОБОРОТ с использование Р.п.: две (ж.р.) женщины (это правильно) и  ДВА (м.р.) МУЖЧИНЫ (это неправильно, грамматика и смысл не сочетаются друг с другом). В этом случае наличие мужчин в женском коллективе не приветствуется (смайлик).
3. Тогда мы берем СОБИРАТЕЛЬНОЕ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ, делаем замену и получаем "ДВОЕ МУЖЧИН" - и  пусть это будут только одни мужчины. Итак, две женщины - двое мужчин. Кстати, выражение "два юноши" звучит плохо, хотя и употребляется в речи. А вот "два друга - двое друзей, два мальчика - двое мальчиков" - эти словосочетания используются одинаково часто.
4. Считается, что собирательные числительные выражают совокупность, но практически они, скорее, имеют ГРАММАТИЧЕСКОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ: соединяются с существительными только мн. числа (двое ножниц) или с существительными некоторых тематических групп, в том числе с одуш. сущ. м. рода (двое юношей). При этом в косвенных падежах они уступают место обычным числительным: двое ножниц - двух ножниц (обязательно), двое мужчин - двух мужчин (желательно).

Comment: Два юноши" ЖЕЛАТЕЛЬНО заменить на "двое юношей", но не обязательно -  так говорят нам правила. А почему такое внимание к существительным м.рода на А/Я? И все-таки лично вы говорите "два мужчины", этот оборот  не кажется Вам странным? Я задавала такой вопрос своим знакомым, и им это выражение не нравилось. Думаю, что как только люди перестанут различать на слух "два мужчины- двое мужчин", мы сразу перейдем к "двоим дочерям" тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, причина в истории собирательных числительных. Собирательные числительные в старославянском языке в ед. ч. выступали в ср. р., а во мн. и дв. ч. имели формы всех трех родов. Потом произошла грамматическая контаминация в связи с утратой двойственного числа, изменением склонений разных групп числительных, изменяющихся по местоимённому и именному склонению.В XVIII веке ведущую роль в системе собирательных числительных приобретает генетически вторичная форма номинатива, восходящая к среднему роду.Собирательные числительные теперь склоняются как имена прилагательные во множественном числе. Сочетаемость тоже изменилась, исчезла сочетаемость с женским родом. Правда, в просторечии возможно услышать и сочетание "двое дочерей"-отзвук истории.

http://bookzie.com/book_522_glava_36_CHISLITELNYE.html

Comment: Происхождение различной сочетаемости собирательных  числительных с существительными  ж. и м. рода объясняет историческая грамматика, однако в современном языке это различие  будет СОХРАНЯТЬСЯ в том случае, если  оно обусловлено  какими-то  причинами, действующими до настоящего времени. И скорее всего, это различие бы исчезло ( а оно имеет такую тенденцию), если бы не один важный момент.

Comment: Это необходимость ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОГО  ПРОТИВОПОСТАВЛЕНИЯ  ВЫРАЖЕНИЙ    «две (три)  женщины – двое (трое) мужчин», так как  НЕКОРРЕКТНО ЗВУЧИТ «две мужчины, три мужчины». Таким образом, если бы в   1-ом склонении не присутствовали бы существительные двух родов, которые не различаются по форме, то, возможно,  мы бы уже использовали  собирательные существительные двое-трое и для женского рода тоже.

Comment: При чём здесь склонение существительных, если числительные 1-4 были прилагательными, только 5-10 - существительными , соотносящимися с 3 современным склонением? Три мужчины-вполне приемлемо, как и два мужчины, формы два-две имеют род.Вижу трёх мужчин и троих мужчин - оба варианта приемлемы.

Comment: 1. Трое мужчин и трех мужчин - это норма (желательно переходить в косвенных падежах от собирательных числительных к количественным). 2. Но здесь речь идет именно  об И.п. Вы допускаете в Вашей речи выражения "две мужчины, три мужчины"? Они звучат совершенно нелепо.

Comment: София, почему же "две мужчины", когда есть двА мужчины? И в чём нелепость, когда это один из возможных вариантов?

Comment: Извините, я конечно же имела в виду "два мужчины, три мужчины". Вот эти выражения вы используете в речи или заменяете их на "двое мужчин, трое мужчин"?

Comment: Я говорю лишь о Вашей категоричности. В правилах пишется:Предпочтительно употребление собирательных числительных  с существительными мужского рода, имеющими в именительном падеже единственного числа окончание -а: двое мужчин, трое дедушек. О запрете речи нет.Это употребление собирательных числительных ограничено,и даже стилем речи: в официальной речи предпочтительны количественные ч.: Требуются на работу четыре инженера (а не «четверо инженеров»).

Comment: Думаю, дело не в два-две: есть же оба-обе, дело в ограниченном сочетании собирательных сущ., которые имеют в совр. форме только значение среднего рода двоЕ, троЕ,именно это запрещает употреблять их с сущ. жен.рода.Дети же содержат в себе именно усреднённое значение- дитё, дитя. Множественное число тоже несёт в себе невыраженность рода.

Answer (score 0):

> Но подобное сочетание в форме "двое дочерей" не употребляется. В чём причина?

В русском языке эти собирательные числительные нормативно используются только по отношению к одушевленным существительным мужского рода - да и то далеко не всяким, преимущественно к людям - и опять-таки не ко всем.

Все примеры обратного объясняются отступлениями от общей нормы.

Если я правильно понимаю ситуацию, то это рудимент какой-то очень древней формы, существовавшей в дописьменный период. Возможно, что для других существительных существительных (в первую очередь для обозначающих женщин) тоже когда-то существовали такие формы, но скорее всего он отличались от "мужских" и были утеряны языком.